# Scala compilation issues with generic parameters in provided examples

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming

I consider online scala examples. Some of them can't be compiled because missed code part.

So to play with function:

```
def fold[A, B](t: Tree[A])(f: A => B)(g: (B, B) => B): B = t match {
  case Leaf(a) => f(a)
  case Branch(l, r) => g(fold(l)(f)(g), fold(r)(f)(g))
}
```

I've defined and used next classes:

```
sealed abstract class Tree[A]
case class Leaf[A](leaf:A) extends Tree
case class Branch[A](left:Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree
```

### Question.

As result I've got compilation some issues.

for `case class Leaf[A](leaf:A) extends Tree`

```
type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type Any)
 required: A
```

and for `case class Branch[A](left:Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree`

```
type mismatch;
 found   : A => B
 required: Any => ?
```

Is any ideas how to fix?

### P.S.

To play with the sample you can use online [scala repl with provided code](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/9ES1Ttw1RNydIexxzukmzw)

### P.S.2.

I tried to use `treat` but it leads to different compilation issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `A` type variable in `Leaf[A]` isn't linked in any way to the type variable in `Tree[_]`.
To fix your compilation issue, you should extend `Tree[A]` instead:

```scala
sealed abstract class Tree[A]
case class Leaf[A](leaf:A) extends Tree[A]
case class Branch[A](left:Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```